# Finding "all solutions" of x in A.x = b in the finite field domain

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, galois-field

Matlab provides a way to find a particular solution to Ax=b in GF(2^m). Here is the link http://www.mathworks.in/help/comm/ref/gflineq.html But it gives only one solution. How can I find the rest of the solutions?

Eg: A=[1 0 2 0 0 1] in GF(4), b=[0] in GF(4). x=A\b gives [0 0 0 0 0 0]' as the solution. I also know [0 1 2 3 2 3]' to be one other solution. But I cannot get any other solution except all zero.How to find all solutions in Matlab?

Comment: Please note that `b=0` is the only case for which you need to find multiple solutions, all other cases are a combination of a single solution to the actual right-hand-side, superimposed with all solutions to `b=0`.  Often the terms *particular solution* and *homogenous solutions* are used for this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In General,

The solutioin to the matrix equation Ax=b need not exist and even if it does, need not be unique. In your case, you know that multiple solutions exist. In such a situation, you have a "particular solution" which is basically, any x that solves Ax=b and now, to get multiple solutions, you can keep adding vectors from the Nullspace of A.

Proof:

Let x be a particular solution and y be in the Nullspace of A (any vector in Nullspace is OK). We know Ax=b. We also know Ay=0. Add them up, A(x+y)=b.

---

TL;DR Solution:

Find the Nullspace of the Matrix in GF and add any vector of the Nullspace to the particular solution to generate more solutions.

I have not used it but [there seems to be a code on MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28633-gfnull) which finds the Nullspace of a Matrix in GF.

Comment: I know Ax=b can have multiple solutions. I am interested in GF(2^m). In my example, there cannot be infinite solution for GF(4) since the elements are limited. All I am looking for is a way to do it in matlab. I will try to use the code in MATLAB central to see if it works. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hats off to you man for so lucidly explaining this concept. We have been struggling at this for so long and it turns out to be so simple. That is why I love Maths. Cheers!